# how to make a loop for a function

Tags: r, equation

this is my dataset:

```
Tree     a    b       k
4412    17.54   14.88   0.0757
4413    53.85   5.89    0.03
4414    24.01   13.09   0.0681
4415    34.94   6.81    0.0341
4416    24.05   7.96    0.0436
4417    36.6    10.42   0.0524
4418    31.77   13.29   0.0663
```

I want to run this function for each tree. How i can make a loop in r?

```
a <- (DF$a)
b<- (DF$b)
k <- (DF$k)
t <- seq(100, 365,1)

y <- a*exp(-exp(b - k*t))
plot(y~t )
```

Comment: I think you need to change the `,` to `.` or so to have the column class as `numeric`.  May be use `dec=','` in the `read.csv`

Comment: yes i define the space in read.csv, but i need to make a loop to compute the value of y for each tree

Comment: Use an apply function with your function as its anonymous function.  If you present your data again (with periods rather than commas or better still as a reproducible example) I (or more likely someone else) will test and post the answer for you.

Comment: To transliterate the data to numeric: `DF[,4:6] <- sapply(colnames(DF[,4:6]),function(x) { as.numeric(gsub(",",".",DF[,x])) })` But I still don't understand the k*t (length are different)

Comment: @Tensibai this is the Gompertz function which estimate the growth for the period of t so the length of t can be different with other parameters.

Comment: Please provide desired output for this perticular data set

Comment: @Madamespring in your mind, k is a single number right ? in your example you're using it as a vector of length 7

Comment: @   David Arenburg the out put is a y value for each tree, actualy this y value provides an s shape  Gompertz function.

Comment: @ Tensibai each parameters of a b k are different for each tree.

Comment: @Madamespring an example with values please ? I really can't get around what you want to do, and I'm not in mood to read the whole wikipedia page about this function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with anonymous functions to loop through each Tree in the dataset , generate plot data and collect the plot object . Assuming your dataset is named `df`...

```
     t <- (seq(100, 365, 1))



     plot_list <-  lapply(split(df, df$Tree), function(x) {  


        y <- x[['a']] * exp(-exp(x[['b']] - x[['k']]*t))


        plot_data <- data.frame(t=t,y=y)

        plt <- plot(y~t, data = plot_data)
        plt
}
)
```

This will return a list object where every element is the plot object for a given tree.

Comment: thank you this is working, but i dont understand   why you did numeric(2))

Comment: I would create T outside the loop, there's no reason to create the same thing again and again.